# Polygon to polyline conversion in ArcMap: multiple entries in attribute table for the same line segment, why?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, polyline-creation

I have converted a polygon shapefile to polyline. I am having hard time understanding the polyline's attribute table. Below is part of the table:

```
objectid    left_fid    right_fid   shape_leng
2              44           6           .0117896
3              44           44          .0117896
4              6            6           .0117896
5              6            44          .0117896
6             -1            44          .0667701
7             -1            6           .0667701
```

I am looking at the border segments: the variable shape_leng indicates unique segments of the border. For example, objects 2-5 all indicate a single segment, with polygons 44 and 6 across the border. Objects 6 and 7 indicate another segment of the border, again with polygons 44 and 6 across the border.

What I don't understand is why the attribute table includes several rows for the same line segment? And how I should read left_fid and right_fid?

Comment: I suspect that you have polygons with coincident edges.

Comment: It is likely. I would replace left_fid and right_fid with 44 and 6 in the example (I need this data to be used somewhere else). But I replacing -1 with 44 or 6 is not helpful, because sometime -1 means that across the border is ocean.

Comment: Try using Create Fishnet to create two adjacent polygons in a feature class. Then Polygon To Line them and examine the output. I suspect this will shed some light on your result by examining simpler data before moving to potentially more complex.  Looking back at the tool documentation may also be helpful.

Comment: You should certainly verify/repair topology before running PolygonToPolyline.